# Proof of $CFE \implies BPI$

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

(CFE): Every filter of closed sets can be extended to a maximal one.

(BPI): Every Boolean algebra contains a prime ideal.

I am reading Herrlich's and Stepran's paper "Maximal filters, continuity and choice principles" where on page 700 it is stated that $CFE \implies BPI$ obviously holds.

Unfortunately, it's not obvious to me. My first idea was that it might hold that a maximal closed filter is prime. But I don't see how to prove it. To recall the definitions, a filter $F$ is prime iff $x \lor y \in F$ implies $x \in F$ or $y \in F$ where $\lor$ denotes the join/supremum. In a partial order of closed sets the order $A \le B$ would be defined by $A \subseteq B$ (or not?). Then $A \lor B$ would be $A \cup B$ and it is not clear to me how $A \cup B \in F$ implies that either $A \in F$ or $B\in F$. And I think the following provides a counter example: Let $X$ be a topological space endowed with the trivial topology. Let $A,B$ be any two non-empty disjoint subsets with $A \cup B = X$. Then $F = \{A \cup B\}$ is a maximal filter on $X$ that is not prime since neither $A$ nor $B$ are in it.

Hence my question: would someone post a proof of the obvious implication $CFE \implies BPI$? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your example, it seems as though $A$ and $B$ are not even part of your Boolean algebra (of closed subsets of $X$).

Comment: Having a tag just for choice principles seems to be excessive. All this is in the topic of axiom of choice anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was making my life too complicated in earlier versions.

Note, first, that $\mathsf{BPI}$ is equivalent (under $\mathsf{ZF}$) to the "Ultrafilter Theorem": Every filter of subsets of a set $S$ can be extended to an ultrafilter.  (See Jech, *The Axiom of Choice*, Theorem 2.2, p.17.)

If $\mathcal{F}$ is any filter of subsets of a set $S$, give $S$ the discrete topology.  As $\mathcal{F}$ is now a filter of closed subsets of $S$, by $\mathsf{CFE}$ it can be extended to a maximal filter $\mathcal{G}$ of closed sets.  Since we have taken the discrete topology, it is easy to show that $\mathcal{G}$ is actually an ultrafilter on $S$ extending $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @MattN. I think I need to do some major fixes.  The argument that $O_x \cup O_y = O_{x \vee y}$ is incorrect (not every subset of $\{ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 \}$ is either a subset of $\{ 1 , 2 \}$ or a subset of $\{ 3 , 4 \}$), and the set inclusions go the opposite way they "should" go.  I'll be thinking about this more closely.

Comment: You're right of course. If $z \le x \lor y$ then it doesn't follow that $z$ is less-equals $x$ or less-equals $y$, it could be uncomparable for both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I think taking $I = \{O_x \mid O_x^c \in \mathcal F\}$ works. It is an ideal: (i) Let $O_x \in I$ and $O_y \subseteq O_x$. Then $O_x^c \subseteq O_y^c$ hence $O_y^c \in \mathcal F$. (ii) Let $O_y \cup O_x \in I$. Then $(O_x \cup O_y)^c = O_x^c \cap O_y^c \in \mathcal F$ and hence both $O_x$ and $O_y$ are in $I$. For primality, let $O_x \cap O_y \in I$. Assume neither $O_x^c$ nor $O_y^c$ are in $\mathcal F$. Then the filter generated by $\mathcal F \cup \{O_x^c\}$ is a proper filter properly containing $\mathcal F$, contradicting maximality of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: @MattN.: In (ii) you should be demonstrating if $x , y \in I$ then $x \vee y \in I$; you seem to be going the opposite way.  (Though the rest is correct.)

Comment: Now I'm trying to show $BPI \implies UFT$ but how do you get from the existence of _a_ prime ideal $J$ that it contains the ideal dual to the filter you start with? Something seems to be missing...

Comment: @MattN.  For $\mathsf{BPI}\Rightarrow\mathsf{UFT}$, if $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on a set $S$, let $\mathcal{I}=\mathcal{F}^\perp$ be the ideal dual to $\mathcal{F}$, and consider the quotient $\mathcal{P}(S)/\mathcal{I}$ (_i.e._, $A,B\subseteq S$ are equivalent iff $A \mathop{\triangle}B\in\mathcal{I}$). This can be shown to be a Boolean algebra under the natural operations.  By $\mathsf{BPI}$ there is a prime ideal $J$ in $\mathcal{P}(S)/\mathcal{I}$.  Now consider $\mathcal{G}=\{A\subseteq S:[S\setminus A] \notin J \}$. This can be shown to be an ultrafilter on $S$ extending $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Should it be $\mathcal G = \{A \subseteq S : [S \setminus A] \in J \}$? I can't seem to show it contains $\mathcal F$ if I use the definition with $\notin J$. With $\in J$ I can.

Comment: @MattN.  You are correct about the correction (how's that for redundancy!).  That $\mathcal{G}$ extends $\mathcal{F}$ follows from the fact that the ideal $J$ in $\mathcal{P} (S) / \mathcal{I}$ contains the zero element, which is $[ \emptyset ] = \mathcal{I}$.

Comment: Now I'm trying to do $UFT \implies BPI$. My idea is to consider the set of all subsets of the Boolean algebra and extend a filter on that set to an ultra filter $U$ and then to show that the set $I = \{ \land A \mid A^c \in U\}$ is a prime ideal. Am I on the right track with this idea? Of course I need to still tweak it a bit, it doesn't quite work yet.

Comment: I think I'll come back to this proof later. I suspect one can use Stone's representation theorem to proof $UFT \implies BPI$ but I'd have to work out the details to confirm this suspicion. Also, it would be an unsatisfactory route since it would use the fact that Stone is equivalent to BPI...

Comment: @MattN.  Sorry, but I haven't been able to spend much time thinking about this today (and unlike Asaf and Brian, I _need_ to spend time thinking about non-Choice issues).  I have some doubts about your first attempt for $\mathsf{UFT} \Rightarrow \mathsf{BPI}$, but the second idea would work, even if it was unsatisfactory.  I'll try to come back to this later today or tomorrow.

Comment: No rush, I am now busying myself with working through Asaf's answer to my previous question and the related paper.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is correct, but we have to work only in the context of Boolean algebras, because that is what $\sf BPI$ gives us.

In this context prime filters are maximal filters. Suppose $B$ is a Boolean algebra, $F\subseteq B$ is a prime filter, and $a\in B$ is any element. Then $a+(-a)\in F$, and therefore either $a\in F$ or $-a\in F$. So we cannot extend $F$, otherwise there would be some $a\in B$ such that $a\notin F$ and $-a\notin F$ either.

Now the implication should be more obvious. Assume $\sf CFE$, and let $B$ be a Boolean algebra. Take $F$ to be a filter on $B$, in order to use $\sf CFE$ we need to find a topological space such that $B$ is isomorphic to its closed sets, but that's easy if we think of $B$ with its order as a topological space.

Comment: Are you using what Arthur is doing in his answer? Otherwise I don't know what a closed filter in a Boolean algebra is.

Comment: @Matt: Boolean algebras carry an order (which is definable from addition and/or multiplication). This order defines a topology. In this topology you can replace each point by a subset of $B$ which is closed, then the filter is translated to a closed filter. This is what Arthur pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

Theorem $2$ of Kyriakos Keremedis and Eleftherios Tachtsis, [*On the extensibility of closed filters in $T_1$ spaces and the existence of well orderable filter bases*](https://eudml.org/doc/248403), Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae, Vol. 40 (1999), No. 2, 343-353, is that $CFE_0$ is equivalent to $AC$, where $CFE_0$ is the statement that every closed filter in a $T_0$ space extends to a maximal closed filter. The proof is given in its entirety. Since we know that $AC\to BPI$, this establishes the result.

Comment: Herrlich also points this out in this book (which was written after both papers were published).

Comment: @Asaf: Theorem $4.32$? (Took me a few minutes to find it. I don’t think that I’d noticed it on previous browses.)

Comment: Along with Corollary $4.32$, yes.